Possible distinction between operator-valued scalar & vectors functions in QM
Quantities in classical physics that behave as scalars and vectors (under rotation) become scalar and vector operators in quantum mechanics (QM). For example, the momentum $\mathbf{p}$ and the kinetic energy $\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}$, which are respectively, a vector and a scalar quantity in classical physics, become a vector and a scalar operator in QM, respectively. A scalar operator, $S$, satisfies $$[S,J_i]=0, \forall i,\tag{a}$$ while the components of a vector operator, $V_j$, satisfies $$[V_j,J_k]=i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}V_\ell, ~\forall j,k.\tag{b}$$ Here, $J_i=L_i+S_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of the total angular momentum operator. Thus, scalars and vectors have very specific commutation relations, which can be used to make a distinction between them.
I am in a little doubt about the status of scalar and vector functions of the position (not simple scalars or vectors), in QM. For example, a spin-independent potential energy function of the type $$U(\mathbf{r})\equiv U(r,\theta,\phi),$$
is not a scalar operator in QM because $$[U(\mathbf{r}), J_i]=[U(\mathbf{r}), L_i+S_i]=[U(\mathbf{r}), L_i]\neq 0,\tag{c}$$ unless $U(\mathbf{r})\equiv U(r)$. Therefore, unlike (a), operator-valued scalar functions do not seem to have a definite commutator with $J_i$'s. The same appears to be the case for operator-valued vector functions in QM, for example, the vector potential, $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$.
Is this true? Is there really no way to distinguish a scalar function from a vector function in QM, based on commutators with $J_i$'s?

did you perhaps mean to write scalar operators before do not instead of scalars? Otherwise this would be in contradiction with what you stated in the previous paragraphs

Indeed as you observed, in classical physics $V=V(\vec{x})$ is not a scalar, it is a scalar field under rotations.
When viewed as an operator which is a function of the position operators it transforms correspondingly:
$$U_R V(\vec{x})U_R^\dagger = V(R\vec{x})$$
and not as a scalar operator. In particular, the commutator of $V$ and $J_k$ is not zero. If $V$ is sufficiently regular,  it can be explicitely computed in terms of matrix generators of rotations in the physical space $(S_k)_{ij}=-\epsilon_{kij}$:
$$[V(\vec{x}),J_k] = -i\hbar S_k \vec{x} \cdot \nabla V(\vec{x})\tag{1},$$
that is (using the summation of repeated indices convention)
$$[V(\vec{x}),J_k] = i \hbar \epsilon_{kij} x_j \partial_iV(\vec{x})\tag{1'}$$
Identity (1) (or (1')) completely characterizes scalar field operators (with respect to rotations).
Similarly $\vec{A}(\vec{x})$, viewed as an operator, transforms like a vector field under the action of the unitary representation of rotations:
$$U_R \vec{A}(\vec{x})U_R^\dagger = R\vec{A}(R\vec{x}).$$
The infinitesimal version of this  identity differs  from (1) due to the expansion of the first factor $R$ in the right hand side:
$$[A_b(\vec{x}),J_k] = i \hbar \epsilon_{kij} x_j \partial_iA_b(\vec{x})
+ i\hbar \epsilon_{kbc} A_c(\vec{x}).$$
In summary, yes,  the commutation rules with the three $J_k$ permit to distinguish beween scalar and vector field operators.

Also, would the same operator $U_R$ be able to correctly transform both a scalar field and a vector field operator? I am thinking that the operator would be unaware of the vector transformation property of $\vec {A} (\vec{X})$. e.g. if we apply it to the x-component of $\vec{A}$, it would simply rotate it like a scalar field, i.e. $U_R A_x (\vec{X})U^{\dagger}_R= A_x(R\vec{X})$, which would be the wrong transformation of $A_x$.

But, if we make $\vec{A} (\vec {x})$ a dynamical degree of freedom, then the Hilbert space enlarges (after quantising both $x$ and $\vec{A(\vec{x})}$) and we would be able to correctly rotate both scalar and vector field operators using the same operator $U_R$. Do you think this is correct?

Yes if you make $A$ a new degree of freedom everything goes right automatically. Indeed it was my idea in answering.

Since $\vec r$ is an operator (more specifically the triple of operators $x,y,z$), a function $U(x,y,z)$ is an operator as well. If as a function of classical variables, the function $U$ is not rotationally invariant, then the corresponding operator $U(x,y,z)$ will have non-zero commutator with the angular momentum operators, i.e. it is not a "scalar operator" in the sense the question defines.
There is nothing unusual or bad about this, it is just the quantum statement of the potential $U$ not being spherically symmetric. The problem is simply that the question conflates two different meanings of "scalar":

Being invariant under rotations.
Being a scalar in the sense of a scalar field.

The definition in the question for "scalar operator" reflects the first, but the idea that $U(\vec r)$ is a "scalar function" is the second: Classically $U(\vec r)$ is not a vector field, it's a scalar field $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$. That doesn't mean it's invariant under rotations unless $U$ is spherically symmetric.
So there is no inconsistency, a classical scalar didn't turn suddenly into a quantum non-scalar, we just need to be careful about the ambiguous meanings of the word "scalar".

There are indeed two notions of scalars/vectors here. One of those is what we employ when we say "scalar/vector operator".
First notion There is the notion of a scalar valued function on a manifold, $f(x)$. The definition is that such a function is a scalar if it transforms to $f(g^{-1}(x))$ under arbitrary diffeomorphisms $x\to g(x)$. In particular, under rotations, the scalar function transforms to $f(R_{\theta} x)$.
This notion indeed carries over to the quantum theory as well. Barring some technicalities about operators, I would expect $U^{\dagger}(R)f(\vec{X})U(R)= f(R\vec{X})$ to hold for operator-equivalents of scalar functions $f(\vec{x})\to f(\vec{X})$.
But this is not sufficient to call $f(X)$ a scalar-operator, as that terminology is for the following notion:
Second notion The rotation group acts on the operators $A$ on Hilbert space using the action $A(\theta)= U^{\dagger}(R_{\theta}) A U (R_{\theta})$.
An operator is defined to be a scalar operator if $A(\theta)= A(0)=A$ for all $\theta$.
It is in this sense that $\frac{P^2}{2m}$ and $f(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)$ are scalar-operators.
Similarly, you can talk about two notions of vector-operators. Note that the first notion is for general diffeomorphisms on a manifold, while the second notion is for the representation of rotation group on the Hilbert space
